# Document is not active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, electron

Developing a Games Platform using Electron + React.
The games are loaded in an iframe and i'm forced to use a `webview` instead of an `iframe` due to cors issues. And also i'm forced to use React v15.6.2 (no hooks)

The issue i'm trying to fix is exiting the fullscreen mode by loading a preload script (preload.js) to the  webview that shoud capable of executing `document.exitFullscreen()` inside the iframe.

**The is what happens** when Escape is pressed in fullscreen mode:

[image]

I suspect it has to do with the fact that i'm using a Class component, because **i was able to resolve this issue using functional component and hooks**, but it's not an option in my project, so **i will have to fix it without using React version 15.6.2**

**Play.js** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { remote } from 'electron';

import { StyledWebview } from './styled';

class Play extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false,
      height: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
    const webviewTag = document.querySelector('webview');
    webviewTag.addEventListener("dom-ready", function(){
      webviewTag.openDevTools()
    });

    webviewTag.addEventListener('leave-html-full-screen', () => {
      this.setState({ isExpanded: false });
    });
    webviewTag.addEventListener('enter-html-full-screen', () => {
      this.setState({ isExpanded: true });
    });
    webviewTag.getWebContents().on('before-input-event', (e, i) => {
      console.log(i.key);
      if (i.key === 'Escape') {
        this.setState({ isExpanded: false });
        const mainWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
        if (mainWindow.isFullScreen()) {
          mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
          webviewTag.send('exitFullscreen', {
            data: '[DesktopClient]: exit fullscreen from container',
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  }

  updateWindowDimensions = () => this.setState({ height: window.innerHeight });

  render() {
    const { computedMatch, accessToken, memberId, refreshToken } = this.props;
    const { height, isExpanded } = this.state;
    const gameId = computedMatch.params.id;
    const src = `https://.......`;

    return (
      <StyledWebview
        isExpanded={isExpanded}
        contentHeight={height}
        preload="./components/Play/Injection/preload.js"
        src={src}
      />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    accessToken: state.auth.userAuthDetails.accessToken,
    memberId: state.auth.userAuthDetails.memberId,
    refreshToken: state.auth.userAuthDetails.refreshToken,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Play);
```

**preload.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

console.log('injected........'); //this works

ipcRenderer.on('exitFullscreen', () => {
  console.log('document:', document); // this prints the document fine
  document.exitFullscreen(); // TypeError: Document not active <--------------------
});
```